# Web browser event log

Tags: .net, c++, browser

I have to develop a console application that would monitor and list all the events fired by browsers: [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#Internet_Explorer_8), [Mozilla Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) and [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome).

What topics need to be studied? Can you help me in some ways?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might find the following to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137407/is-there-any-way-in-net-to-programmatically-listen-to-http-traffic

Comment: Your question doesn't have much to do with the tags you've assigned.

Comment: could you specify a bit more what you mean by "events fired"? Could you give examples of such events?

Comment: the application is not browser-dependent..

"events fired": e.g. when a user hits browse or go signal in the browser's address bar. the application must now if this will happen..and prints out the event..

Answer (score 1):

If it is Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, I'm pretty much sure you could listen to the events by installing your plug-in/extension in the browser. Doing this is pretty easy in these browsers.

I'm assuming Chrome for the moment,

```
chrome.tabs.onSelectedChanged(function(){..}); //This will listen to tab-selection related events..
chrome.tabs.onCreate(function(){..}); //This will get fired when a new tab is opened..
```

By writing a plug-in for the browser I'm sure you can listen to hundred more such events!

For Google Chrome refer to: [Link](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)

For Mozilla Firefox refer to: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension)

For Internet Explorer, I believe there is no central place to learn stuff, but I'm sure you will get loads of pages offering you the tutorial. Just google it out! :P

Actually building a console application is kind of difficult; unless you are able to get the HANDLE to the browser, listen for messages passed, catch those event and stuffs like that! If you could tell us what exactly you are trying to do, maybe we can help you! :)

I hope this resolves your query.

Comment: mmmh..the application tends to be browser-independent..or standalone..is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug does this for Mozilla Firefox and had an extension for IE7+ too. Look at the sources for that, since it's Open Source.